# Не могу найти ошибку в задании, прошу помочь советом либо конструктивной критикой!

Tags: python

Моя задача это найти ошибки. Прошу помочь советом, либо конструктивной критикой.

Эта программа запрашивает у пользователя сначала количество имён, потом - имена, и формирует из них список.

Из этих имён на экран выводятся только те, которые начинаются с заглавной буквы "А".

```
def make_list(number):
    names = []
    for item in number:
        names.append(input('Введите имя с заглавной буквы'))
        print(names)

number = int(input('Сколько имен надо ввести?'))
names = make_list(number)

for name in names:
    if name[1] == 'А':
        print('Имя', name, 'Начинается с буквы А')
```

Comment: Дайте индексируемый заголовок вопросу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Диапазон цикла:

```
for item in range(number):
```

Функция должна возвращать результат

```
return names
```

Нумерация символов в строке - с нуля, а не с 1

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_list(number):
    names = []
    for item in range(number):
        names.append(input("Введи имя с заглавной")) 
    return names

number = int(input("сколько имен"))
names = make_list(number)
print (names)
for name in names:
    if name[0] == "A":
        print ("имя", name, " на а")
```

Пояяснения:

`for item in range(number):` -цикл

`return names` - нам не нужно печатать список, а нужно возвратить результат функции в программу

`if name[0] == "A":` - первая буква имеет индекс 0

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: if name[0] == "A":